# How can I scope three different conditions using the same loop in Java?

Tags: java

I would like to count `countX` and `countX` using the same loop instead of creating three different loops. Is there any easy way approaching that?

```
public class Absence {
    private static File file = new File("/Users/naplo.txt");
    private static File file_out = new File("/Users/naplo_out.txt");
    private static BufferedReader br = null;
    private static BufferedWriter bw = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int countSign = 0;
        int countX = 0;
        int countI = 0;
        String sign = "#";
        String absenceX = "X";
        String absenceI = "I";

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file_out));

            String st;
            while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
                for (String element : st.split(" ")) {

                    if (element.matches(sign)) {
                        countSign++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (element.matches(absenceX)) {
                        countX++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (element.matches(absenceI)) {
                        countI++;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("2. exerc.: There are " + countSign + " rows int the file with that sign.");
            System.out.println("3. exerc.: There are " + countX + " with sick note, and " + countI + " without sick note!");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Absence.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**text file example:**

```
# 03 26
Jujuba Ibolya IXXXXXX
Maracuja Kolos XXXXXXX
```

Comment: You mean if statements instead of loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant using less than 3 `if` statements. You can actually so it with no ifs.

In your for loop write this:

```
Countsign += (element.matches(sign)) ? 1 : 0;
CountX += (element.matches(absenceX)) ? 1 : 0;
CountI += (element.matches(absenceI)) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: There's no need for `continue` because there's is no way `match` is going to be true for 3 different strings.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me. What I need is to loop through the text file and count how many elements of '#', 'X', and 'I' are in the file. It went well with '#' but no clue how to make it with 'X', and 'I' using the same loop. With your provided code I still get 0, 0 `countX` and `countI`.

Comment: So, it worked with sign but not with X and I? It is weird it is doing the same thing for all 3 strings so it should count them correctly.

Comment: Did you write anything else in the for loop?

Comment: No I didn't. But I edited my question with a snippet from the text file. And I just realised that I need to loop the text through char by char I guess unlike in the provided code above.

Answer (score 1):

Both answers check if the word (`element`) matches all regular expressions while this can (and should, if you ask me) be avoided since a word can match only one regex. I am referring to the `continue` part your original code has, which is good since you do not have to do any further checks.

So, I am leaving here one way to do it with Java 8 Streams in "one liner".

But let's assume the following regular expressions:

```
String absenceX = "X*";
String absenceI = "I.*";
```

and one more (for the sake of the example):

```
String onlyNumbers = "[0-9]*";
```

In order to have some matches on them.

The text is as you gave it.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
        File txtFile = new File(desktop, "test.txt");

        String sign = "#";
        String absenceX = "X*";
        String absenceI = "I.*";
        String onlyNumbers = "[0-9]*";
        List<String> regexes = Arrays.asList(sign, absenceX, absenceI, onlyNumbers);

        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(txtFile.toPath());

        //@formatter:off
        Map<String, Long> result = lines.stream()
                .flatMap(line-> Stream.of(line.split(" "))) //map these lines to words
                .map(word -> regexes.stream().filter(word::matches).findFirst()) //find the first regex this word matches
                .filter(Optional::isPresent) //If it matches no regex, it will be ignored
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Optional::get, Collectors.counting())); //collect
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

The result:

> {X*=1, #=1, I.*=2, [0-9]*=2}

**X*=1** came from word: `XXXXXXX`

**#=1** came from word: `#`

**I.*=2** came from words: `IXXXXXX` and `Ibolya`

**[0-9]*=2** came from words: `03` and `06`

Ignore the fact I load all lines in memory.

Answer (score 0):

So I made it with the following lines to work. It escaped my attention that every character need to be separated from each other. Your ternary operation suggestion also nice so I will use it.

```
String myString;
        while ((myString = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String newString = myString.replaceAll("", " ").trim();
            for (String element : newString.split(" ")) {

                countSign += (element.matches(sign)) ? 1 : 0;
                countX += (element.matches(absenceX)) ? 1 : 0;
                countI += (element.matches(absenceI)) ? 1 : 0;
```